# How to define generic interfaces for the same Fortran function body

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I want to implement a generic interface in Fortran to call a function with either REAL or COMPLEX type variables. Since the function itself is quite extensive, I want to let both single interfaces access the same function body.

Using a simple addition problem as an example, i would like to have an callable interface `addfun` which takes two variables of either REAL or COMPLEX type and returns their sum. As mentioned before i want the functions to share the same body `z  = x+y` to avoid having to implement it twice.

My attempt so far looks like this:

```
module varaddition
    interface
        module function add_c(x, y) result(z)
            complex(kind=8) :: x,y,z
        end function add_c

        module function add_r(x, y) result(z)
            real(kind=8) :: x,y,z
        end function add_r
    end interface

    ! defining an common interface
    interface addfun
        procedure :: add_c, add_r
    end interface addfun

end module varaddition

submodule (varaddition) varaddition_s
    contains
    ! attempt to set the same body to both single interfaces by simply
    ! assigning it to the generic interface
    module procedure addfun
        z  = x+y
    end procedure addfun
end submodule varaddition_s

program addTest

    use varaddition

    real(kind=8) :: xr,yr,zr
    complex(kind=8) :: xc,yc,zc

    xr = 1d0
    yr = 2d0
    zr = addfun(xr, yr)
    print*, "Result using REAL type variables: ", zr

    xc = complex(1d0,1d0)
    yc = complex(2d0,2d0)
    zc = addfun(xc, yc)
    print*, "Result using COMPLEX type variables: ", zc

end program addtest
```

However, my approach of simply assigning the body to the generic procedure doesn't work that way. Can anyone give me a hint how to solve this?

Comment: Do you know `include`? It is commonly used for this purpose and there are many examples on this site.

Comment: Having got used to template functions in C++ this would really be on my wish-list for Fortran. The nearest I could get was to define the function body in an include file, then "include" that into each function prototype. Worked for merge sort. Probably not worth it for just adding two elements.

Comment: @lastchance Generic programming is planned for the future standard revision. But not as powerful as C++ templates that allow metaprogramming and compile time complicated calculations.

Comment: Ah, I live in hope!

Comment: Check https://github.com/j3-fortran/generics

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. I even thought about to use include but  I would like to avoid putting the function body in a separate file. But when i understand you correctly, it seems to be the only option at the moment.